# Windows 10 issue: DevMgmt.msc & AppWiz.cpl hung indefinitely after trying to switch from static IP to DHCP on NIC

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers

I installed a new Cisco switch in my home lab yesterday. My Dell Precision T3620 was using a static IP, but had a network issue so I set the NIC to use DHCP. This resolved the network issue temporarily, but then it recurred about 10 minutes later. All other devices on my LAN were working normally (so no DHCP issues), so I attempted to uninstall/reinstall the NIC driver, plus uninstall Cisco AnyConnect (not being used anymore - just want to remove to simplify network setup on the machine).

At this point, Device Manager (DevMgmt.msc) and Add/Remove Programs (AppWiz.cpl) hung indefinitely - for over 2 hours. I rebooted the machine and tried to use the static IP I was using previously: this failed and the NIC kept disabling itself in Windows. So once again, I tried DevMgmt.msc (to uninstall/reinstall driver) & AppWiz.cpl (to remove Cisco AnyConnect) but the exact same thing happened again. What could be the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `CHKDSK /F /R` and rebooting fixed this issue.